# Where is the right place for the database of a program on Windows 7?

Tags: database, vb.net, local-database

I wrote a programm(VB.NET 2010) with an local database(.SDF). Now im going to add a Setup.
Where should I place the database? Where is the usually place, for database?
OS = Windows 7

**C:\ProgramData (COMMONAPPDATAFOLDER)** or **C:\Program Files(x86)** aren't good ideas, because the normal local client has there only read and execute permission. The normal client should be able to modify the database.

I hope you can help me. Thank you! BK_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`C:\ProgramData` should be written by any user on the computer.

If you want a per-user database, put it under `Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData`, if you want a per-computer, put under `Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData`.

See well know location here: [Environment.SpecialFolder Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx)

Comment: Yes, but if I place the database into "C:\ProgramData" the normal user has only Read and Execute permission and not Modify. That does not do it for me. Because when I execute my program I need to take changes with the current User on the Database. What do you mean with per-user and per-computer?

Comment: Per-User means that there will be one database for each user. Per-Computer will mean that there will be one database but all users of that computer will be able to access it.

Comment: @BK_: on a standard computer, users of the computer **have** rights to  write into subfolders under ProgramData. If you put your DB in a subfolder (ie. `c:\ProgramData\YourCOmpany\YouApp\yourdb.sdx`), all users should have the permissions to edit the file.

Comment: @SteveB Are you sure? My computer is a standard computer(without GPO), and also there isnt edit permission. I searched my problem in the internet and i can see that other people have also the same problem. But nowhere is exists a solution.
Thanks Mych!

Comment: @Bk_: If you switch to the advanced permission window of this folder, you will see that there is a specific rule. For users, read only on the files within the folder, but not on the subfolder. If you are not convinced, launch notepad without elevated privileges and try to create a folder and write a file from notepad.

Comment: @SteveB Yes, there is the permission with specific rule. Also if I create manually a notepad file, I can edit it. This is no problem. But I have to run the setup.exe with as an admin user. And than the database hasn't 'edit' permission for the current user (only execute and read)